# Convert bigint value formatted as 20200321 to datetime formatted as '2020-03-21 00:00:00'

Tags: sql-server

How do we convert the `bigint` value `20200321` which is a `date(2020-03-21` i.e., `21st March, 2020)` to `datetime` format `'2020-03-21 00:00:00'` so that we can map with other tables

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it like this :

```
select cast('20200321' as datetime2)
```

[SQL Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/55dbbf/2)

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `bigint` to `varchar` first and then cast to `datetime`.

```
declare @a as bigint = 20200321;
select CAST(CAST(@A AS varchar) as datetime)
```